# Multiple database transaction management in spring boot 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jta

Hi I have two different database and I need distributed transaction for my process.

Chained transaction manager is deprecated
(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2232)

And after spring boot 3.0 ,spring doesnt support jta solution like atomikos

(https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/issues/175)
(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20809)
So with spring boot 3.0 what is the best way to manage distributed transaction management

Comment: As mentioned in the issue linked. Atomikos isn't supported anymore unless Atomikos supports it themselves. Narayana (as mentioned in the issues) does support Spring Boot so you might want to take a look at that.

Comment: narayana still doenst work in spring boot 3 yet

Comment: Why wouldn't it, it supports JakartaEE so it should work in Spring Boot. It requires manual configuration as there is no Spring Boot auto-configuration but as it uses the proper APIs it should work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you know how to make multiple transactional databases work with the java 17, spring 3.0 and the required jakarta updates for java 17?  There appears to be no or inadequate documentation on the replacement for javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: There is no replacement for `javax.sql.DataSource` because that still `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest (6.0) version of atomikos TransactionEssentials claims to support Jakarta EE. So it should support springboot 3.

See here: https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/blob/master/README.md

You can give it a try with springboot 3 with this starter: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atomikos/transactions-spring-boot3-starter/6.0.0